# How to fix this database schema to avoid inconsistency?

Tags: sql, database, django, database-design, database-normalization

I'm stuck on an issue of database design.  How do I fix this schema to avoid problems with consistent data down the road?

### Let's consider three objects:

(django model definitions below)

- TaskType
- TaskGroup

  - foreignkey to TaskType
- TrainingTask

  - foreignkey to TaskType
  - foreignkey to TaskGroup

The problem (at least I think this is a problem) is that if I have a TrainingTask, then it could potentially have inconsistent values for TaskType (via the direct foreign key and indirectly via the fk to TaskGroup).

### And some "facts" about these objects:

TaskTypes hold meta information about TrainingTasks.  TaskGroups are for grouping tasks of the same type.  Elsewhere in my application I want to be able to take a TaskGroup and say "give me a random TrainingTask from this TaskGroup".

- There can be lots of TrainingTasks for a TaskType.
- All the TrainingTasks in a group should have the same type
- There can be lots of TaskGroups for a TaskType
- TrainingTasks with the same TrainingType can be in different TaskGroups

Also, I am doing all this in Django, and TrainingTask is a subclass of Task (using Multi Table Inheritance), and thus TrainingTask inherits the fk to TaskType from Task.  I would like to keep this structure so that whether I have a Task or TrainingTask in hand I can inquire of it what its TaskType is, e.g. task.task_type or trainingtask.task_type.  The relevant model definitions are:

```
from somewhere import Task

class TaskType(models.Model):
    ...fields...


class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    task_type = models.ForeignKey(TaskType)


class TrainingTask(Task):
    group = models.ForeignKey(TaskGroup)
    #task_type = models.ForeignKey(TaskType)  # FK to TaskType is contained in Task class
```

The current design "feels wrong" because of the multiple paths from TrainingTask to TaskType.  I know I can add a model level integrity check when I save a TrainingTask, which is better than nothing, but it stills seems like it could be better.  As a practical matter it also complicates using automatic fixtures like django-autofixture.

Is my feeling that "this is wrong" misguided?  Or, if not, how do I fix this schema, considering the "facts" given above (especially "All the TrainingTasks in a group should have the same type", which seems to me to preclude eliminating the fk from TaskGroup to TaskType).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that feels wrong to me is:

- If it is the case that EVERY `TrainingTask` MUST have a `TaskGroup`, and their `task_type`'s must be the same
- Then you can get rid of the `TrainingTask.task_type` altogether since it will have access to that through `TrainingTask.group.task_type`.

Otherwise,

- If `TrainingTask` can exist WITHOUT a `TaskGroup`,
- Then that would seem to me to be a sound way to do it.

If the second case is true, then to ensure there are no "inconsistent values  for `TaskType`", you can override the `save()` method of both `TaskGroup` and `TrainingTask`, so that if their `task_type` is changed, either remove all related Groups/Tasks or change the `task_type` of the related Groups/Tasks to the same one.

Comment: It is the case that TrainingTask MUST have a TaskGroup, but TrainingTask inherits the FK to TaskType from the Task class (which does not have a group - at least not as implemented now...though maybe now that I think about it, adding a Group for the base Task class might make sense too)